# Testing If FormBuilder has called the method group on NgOnInit()

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular and angular testing and I have gone through many articles on jasmine testing the formBuilder but did not get much help.

Assume I have the following code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.someForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    formField1: [null, Validators.required],
    formField2: [null, Validators.required],
    formField3: [null, Validators.required]
  });
}
```

Now I want to test ***if group method on formBuilder*** is called or not. How can I do it in Jasmine angular?
I have tried the below code but it is not working:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChangePasswordComponent);
  formBuilder = TestBed.inject(FormBuilder);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});


it('on ngOnit_ FormBuilder object should call group method', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const spyObject =  spyOn(formBuilder, 'group');
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(spyObject).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ngOnInit` is called when `fixture.detectChanges` was first invoked after component creation (in `beforeEach` here)!

So as you are spying on the form builder service after angular life cycle hooks are called there was no call to form builder's `group` method.

Solution:
As `ngOnInit` is just a method called by angular, you can invoke it again yourself and assert.

```
const spyObject = spyOn(formBuilder, 'group');
component.ngOnInit();
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(spyObject).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: I tried this and I am getting an error like "formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in."

Comment: What is the markup for form group you are using? My answer is only to show what was going wrong with your initial approach. You can raise a new issue with current problem or post it as a edit to present question.

Comment: Not sure how you code is organized but did you try `*ngIf="formGroup"` where you are binding the formGroup.

Comment: this is what I used:   <form name=someForm" role="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm();" [formGroup]="someForm">